# CKEditor 5 inline editor features are not working when initiate it with input element

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, editor

I have configure CKEditor 5 for my project as below:

**Html:**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control question_input" placeholder="Question" autocomplete="off">
```

**JavaScript:**

```
InlineEditor
            .create( document.querySelector( '.question_input' ) )
            .catch( error => {
                console.error( error );
            } );
```

It is initiating CKEditor on input but I am not able to use the features of CKEditor like bold, italic etc.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rajtri/gk451vby/3/)

Thanks.

Comment: Your fiddle throws an error `CKEditorError: Permission denied to access property Symbol.toStringTag`.

Later versions of ck5 say that only classicEditor can directly work with inputs

Comment: try again, may be your internet connection had issue, when you tried.